# JuliaPro: Error when trying: Pkg.add("DataFrames")

Tags: csv, julia, atom-editor

When I try to install the package DataFrames it results in an error.
How can I get DataFrames installed?

I am using Julia Pro v1.0.2.1, Atom, Windows 10.

I have tried typing: Pkg.add("DataFrames") in the REPL.
I have tried to restart or turn off/turn on PC and retry.
In the JuliaPro folder in my C-drive there is a folder named "DataFrames".

```
julia> Pkg.add("DataFrames")
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package ForwardDiff [f6369f11]:
 ForwardDiff [f6369f11] log:
 ├─possible versions are: [0.0.2-0.0.3, 0.1.0-0.1.8, 0.2.0-0.2.5, 0.3.0-0.3.5, 0.4.0-0.4.2, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.7.0-0.7.5, 0.8.0-0.8.5, 0.9.0, 0.10.0-0.10.3] or uninstalled
 ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with JuMP [4076af6c] to versions: [0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.7.0-0.7.5, 0.8.0-0.8.5, 0.9.0]
 │ └─JuMP [4076af6c] log:
 │   ├─possible versions are: [0.1.1-0.1.2, 0.2.0, 0.3.0-0.3.2, 0.4.0-0.4.1, 0.5.0-0.5.8, 0.6.0-0.6.3, 0.7.0-0.7.4, 0.8.0, 0.9.0-0.9.3, 0.10.0-0.10.3, 0.11.0-0.11.3, 0.12.0-0.12.2, 0.13.0-0.13.2, 0.14.0-0.14.2, 0.15.0-0.15.1, 0.16.0-0.16.2, 0.17.0-0.17.1, 0.18.0-0.18.5, 0.19.0] or uninstalled
 │   └─restricted to versions 0.18.5 by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.18.5
 ├─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: [0.9.0, 0.10.0-0.10.3] or uninstalled, leaving only versions: 0.9.0 └─restricted by compatibility requirements with DiffRules [b552c78f] to versions: [0.0.2-0.0.3, 0.1.0-0.1.8, 0.2.0-0.2.5, 0.3.0-0.3.5, 0.4.0-0.4.2, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.7.0-0.7.1, 0.10.0-0.10.3] or uninstalled — no versions left
   └─DiffRules [b552c78f] log:
     ├─possible versions are: 0.0.1-0.0.10 or uninstalled
     └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: 0.0.8-0.0.10 or uninstalled
Stacktrace:
 [1] #propagate_constraints!#61(::Bool, ::Function, ::Pkg.GraphType.Graph, ::Set{Int64}) at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\GraphType.jl:1005
 [2] propagate_constraints! at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\GraphType.jl:946 [inlined] [3] #simplify_graph!#121(::Bool, ::Function, ::Pkg.GraphType.Graph, ::Set{Int64}) at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\GraphType.jl:1460
 [4] simplify_graph! at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\GraphType.jl:1460 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
 [5] macro expansion at .\logging.jl:317 [inlined]
 [6] resolve_versions!(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}, ::Nothing) at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:354
 [7] resolve_versions! at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:317 [inlined]
 [8] #add_or_develop#62(::Array{Base.UUID,1}, ::Symbol, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\Operations.jl:1223
 [9] #add_or_develop at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [10] #add_or_develop#13(::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::Function, ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:64
 [11] #add_or_develop at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [12] #add_or_develop#12 at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:29 [inlined]
 [13] #add_or_develop at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [14] #add_or_develop#11 at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:28 [inlined]
 [15] #add_or_develop at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [16] #add_or_develop#10 at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:27 [inlined]
 [17] #add_or_develop at .\none:0 [inlined]
 [18] #add#18 at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:69 [inlined]
 [19] add(::String) at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Pkg\src\API.jl:69
 [20] top-level scope at none:0
```

I would like the DataFrames package installed.

Comment: Have you tried a `Pkg.update()`? That often resolves these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I installed Julia and Atom seperatly. Using this setup instead of JuliaPro is as blessing :-)